# How to add Anchor with clickHandler to ListGridRecord in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I need to add Anchor with clickHandler to ListGridRecord. Click to Anchor should call the function (adding more rows to ListGrid). I'm able to write Anchor with href:

```
private void addAnchorToRecord(ListGridRecord rec) {
    String img  = "<img src='pict/Plus.png'/>";
    Anchor myAnchor = new Anchor(img, true, "example.html");
    String value = myAnchor.toString();
    rec.setAttribute("versions", value);
}
```

But this code:

```
private void addAnchorToRecord(final ListGridRecord rec) {
    String img  = "<img src='pict/Plus.png'/>";
    Anchor myAnchor = new Anchor(img, true);
    myAnchor.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
               addExtraRows(rec);
           }
        });
    String value = myAnchor.toString();
    rec.setAttribute("versions", value);
}
```

doesn't work. I see image, but after click nothing happens. In second case

```
value = "<a href="javascript:;" class="gwt-Anchor"><img src="pict/Plus.png"></a>"
```

I think in this place i lose information about clickHandler. How can I succesful add ClickHandler in this situation?

EDIT

I used LinkItem:

```
private void updateVersions(final ListGridRecord rec) {
    LinkItem linkItem = new LinkItem("link");  
    linkItem.setTitle("LinkItem");  
    linkItem.setLinkTitle("Click Me");  
    linkItem.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            showPreviousVersions(rec);
        }
    });
    rec.setAttribute("versions", linkItem);
}
```

Then in my cell was only "[object Object]"

**Functionality I need: set attribute to ListGridRecord, which has icon and clickHandler.**

Comment: Any reason to use GWT Anchor instead of SmartGWT [LinkItem](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/LinkItem.html)? Also, check http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#form_controls_various , http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_datatypes_link_text , http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_datatypes_link_image

Comment: No reason. I've edited my question.

Comment: Have you checked those SmartGWT showcase links I posted? You are probably trying to do something like [**this**](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_cell_widgets).

Comment: I wanted to set everything in ListGridRecord instead in ListGridField. It was my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its easier if you just add a button in the ListGridRecord and then add a clickhandler to the button. It must be done like this:

When configuring the ListGrid:

```
    setShowRecordComponents      (true );
    setShowRecordComponentsByCell(true );
```

When setting fields

```
    ...
    ListGridField btnField= new ListGridField("btnFieldName", " ");
    ...
```

And then just override createRecordComponent like this:

```
 @Override
 protected Canvas createRecordComponent(final ListGridRecord record, final Integer colNum){
        if(getFieldName(colNum).equalsIgnoreCase(("btnFieldName"))){
               IButton btn= new IButton("");
               //configure the button
               btn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    //your logic
                  }
               });
               return btn;
         }
     return super.createRecordComponent(record, colNum);
 }
```